# Can we create different areas(container) in one azure Redis Cache connection?

Tags: azure-redis-cache

I need to create different areas under one redis cache service in azure. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical databases feature of redis. You can think of each of your areas as a logical database. Alternatively, you can use Redis structures like SETS, HASHTABLES etc., an area mapping to a SET or HASHTABLE.